# Stored procedure in oracle for fetching records based on rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, rownum

I want to fetch records based on row(row number).I've done using sql query itself.

```
select * from (select m.*,rownum r from employees m) where r between 80 and 100
```

But now I want to do the same thing with use of cursors in stored procedure(oracle) to fetch like records between 80 an 100(based on rownum pseudo column).Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you show your SQL query at least?

Comment: @Hawk select * from (select m.*,rownum r from employees m)  where r between 80 and 100

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have a look at [Stored Procedures](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-procedures.htm) and [Cursors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm) to understand the basics. Other than that, your query can be easily enclosed within a cursor and a procedure. If you are going to use explicit cursor, it could be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE stored_procedure_name AS
CURSOR IS
  select * from (select rownum r,salary from employees) where r between 80 and 100;

BEGIN
 open c1; 
 loop 
   fetch c1 
   into a,b; 
   dbms_output.put_line(a || b); 
   exit when c1%notfound; 
 end loop;
 close c1;
END;
```

Comment: i know the basics of cursors but i have a doubt of using which attributes of cursors(found,notfound,rowcount,isopen) to break the loop statement

Comment: declare
a number;
b number;
cursor c1 is select rownum,salary from employees;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into a,b;
dbms_output.put_line(a || b);
exit when c1%rowcount<=25;
end loop;
end;
/

Comment: when i give like that i didnt get what i was actually expected.It just display it as 124000

Comment: @senthilleon You should have mentioned this in your question statement, and pointed out what is your question exactly. For breaking the loop, it depends on how you want to break it. If you want to run the loop over the entire cursor, then `notfound` is the condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is simplified syntax you can use that avoids having to deal with cursors directly. I think it's less error-prone this way.

Example:

```
begin
  for rec in (
    select rn, salary
    from (
      select rownum as rn, salary
      from employees
    ) where rn between 80 and 100
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(rec.rn) || rec.salary);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Documentation: [Query Result Set Processing With Cursor FOR LOOP Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS553)

**EDIT:**

The general form of this construct is:

```
begin
  for rec in (
    select * from employees -- write any SQL you want here
  ) loop

    -- do whatever you need to do inside the loop...
    -- you can access the results of the query through the "rec" variable.
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.column1);
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.column2);
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.column3);

  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: @hawk what if i want to print all the records.How to use same statement for select * from

Comment: Just write the SQL you need and plug it into the `for rec in (sql) loop ... end loop;`.  If you want to select all the records, then plug in `select * from employees`.  Have a look at the documentation link I posted.  It should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple construct like bellow

```
declare
  v_e_row  employees%rowtype; --employees table row type
  v_rownum number;
begin
  for emp in (select * from (select m.* , rownum r from employees m) where r between 80 and 100) 
    loop
      v_e_row.emp_id  := emp.emp_id; -- sample value ( you will get all value including rownum)
      v_rownum := emp.r;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_e_row.emp_id||v_rownum); 
    end loop;
end;
```